# pl/sql: sort by a group, then company, Or append 2 tables

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview, plsql

I donn't know what to do now...
This is what I have now from a query, but I want it to look like something in the table following this one:

```
COMPANYNUM       BALANCE      ROWENTRIES
2            8986762.37       2
125         141390.3          6
124          77431750         4
76           36299.82         6
17           -0.01                76
86           -1               19
500         -2000                 7
1           -101.48             6348
3               0               5
4               0               6
5               0               30
9               0           10
12              0               28
13              0               93
16              0               17
19              0             159
21              0               5
23              0               6
26              0               101      
27              0               1
29              0               2
30              0               14
32              0               6
33              0               110
34              0               27
```

I want it to be like:

```
COMPANYNUM    BALANCE     ROWENTRIES
1             -101.48       6348
2             8986762.37        2
17            -0.01             76
76            36299.82      6
86            -1                19
124           77431750      4
125       141390.3      6
500       -2000             7
3               0               5
4               0               6
5               0               30
9               0           10
12              0               28
13              0               93
16              0               17
19              0             159
21              0               5
23              0               6
26              0               101      
27              0               1
29              0               2
30              0               14
32              0               6
33              0               110
34              0               27
```

I want the order to be like: priority where the balances are not zero, then order by the company number, then append the balance entries that are zeros. Any ideas on how to achieve this in PL/SQL please...

Thanks.

Comment: You need to format your question so it is readable

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you don't want do get a million downvotes, please read this - 
http://sscce.org/ and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask , and then come back.  If you want someone to take time to help you, you should show some level of effort in writing your question.

"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @codingbiz :Thanks for your suggestion. Could you take a look now please? Thanks.

Comment: @OldProgrammer :That was a long comment with so many information but nothing related on the question itself. You should probably go to some English forum for essays or speech too. No offence.

Comment: Wow.  @OldProgrammer was trying to be helpful, so that you get better answers to your questions (or any answers at all).  Perhaps you should take the comment to heart, rather than disagreeing and telling him the comment was useless.  Only 4 of your 31 questions have upvotes, the rest have no votes, or downvotes.  And several don't have any answers.  So maybe you should consider the possibility that you *should* put some more effort into your questions.

Comment: @user2751691 As willing as we (esp. me) like to help, questions needs to be readable and not too long. Right now I can't read meaning to those numbers you post and don't know what they mean, so I don't have a clue what you are up to. And I hope your problem is solved by now... sorry if we could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN Balance <> 0
        THEN COMPANYNUM
   END  NULLS LAST,
   COMPANYNUM
```

See a demo here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/859be/1

Comment: It works, returns correct result table when I tried to run it, but somehow keep giving error of :Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY A.MAIN
Error: ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object SOMERFIL.GLP501@TCHR400.SOME.COM
       ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
       ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
       Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 6553
Line: 1
Text: CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY a.MAIN is              Any ideas please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your database can't establish connection with remote database at compile time. Test your remote link with: `select sysdate from dual@REMOTE_DB_LINK;`, also try to ping to remote database using oracle `tnsping` utility.

Comment: thanks, it was the network issue i guess, it's good now, and ur code works. Thanks a lot.